# Visualize a sequenze of images

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to display some images like this:[image]

The question is not about the arrows, it is about the frames. I want the figure to tell, that each of the images is a frame of one video. Thanks to FHZs hint, I learned what to even search for. This is what I got so far.
[image]
This is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1,0)},y={(0,0.9)},z={({cos(5)},{sin(20)})}]
        
        \node[canvas is yz plane at x = 0, transform shape](p1){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tree1}};
        
        \node[canvas is yz plane at x = 3, transform shape](p2){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tree2}};
        
        \node[canvas is yz plane at x = 6, transform shape](p3){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tree3}};
        
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I think it somewhat makes clear, that the images are frames of a video, yet it doesnt look very nice. So Im open for advice.
Thanks,
Felix

Comment: In this particular case, 3D are not necessary, just some smart perspective. Using TikZ, try to draw the square in this perspective, than use foreach to create multiple copies. Arrows can be drawn an needed.

Comment: You can input every picture as content of a node, then use node option [yslant=.5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Answer consider the first version of question.

With slanted nodes in chain:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                patterns.meta, positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
node distance = 2mm and 1mm,
  start chain = going left,
   arl/.style = {Straight Barb-Straight Barb, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize, align=center},
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=16mm, yslant=0.5, node contents={}, 
                 outer sep=0pt, yshift=8mm, on chain},
    Np/.style = {N, postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=-30,distance={3pt},line width=0.2pt]},
                                pattern color=gray}}
                        ]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
{
\ifnum\x<5
    \node (n\x) [Np];
\else
    \node (n\x) [N];
\fi
}
\coordinate[above=of n1.north east] (t);
\coordinate[below=of n1.south west] (b);
\draw [arr] (t) to ["Transmission Order"] (n8.east |- t);
\draw [arl] (b -| n1.west) to ["Frames in Scene B" '] (b -| n4.west);
\draw [arl] (b -| n5.west) to ["Frames in Scene A" '] (b -| n8.west);
\draw [arr] 
            (n5.west |- b) to ["Scene\\ Change"] (n4.west |-b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                patterns.meta, positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
node distance = 2mm and -8mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arl/.style = {Straight Barb-Straight Barb, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize, align=center},
     N/.style = {draw, fill=white, minimum size=16mm, yslant=0.75, node contents={}, 
                 outer sep=0pt, yshift=-12mm, on chain},
    Np/.style = {N, postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=-30,distance={3pt},line width=0.2pt]},
                                pattern color=gray}}
                        ]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
{
\ifnum\x>4
    \node (n\x) [Np];
\else
    \node (n\x) [N];
\fi
}
\coordinate[above=of n1.north east] (t);
\coordinate[below=of n1.south west] (b);
\draw [arr] (t -| n8.east) to ["Transmission Order"] (t);
\draw [arl] (b -| n1.west) to [bend right=10, "Frames in\\ Scene A"] (b -| n4.west);
\draw [arl] (b -| n5.west) to [bend right=10, "Frames in\\ Scene B"] (b -| n8.west);
\draw [arr] 
            (n4.west |- b) to [bend right=60,"Scene\\ Change"] (n5.west |-b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question for clarification but the answer looks pretty good. Im now trying to apply it to my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `\foreach` loop to draw the figures and also name the nodes. The nodes are called `bottom1`, ..., `bottom8` and `top1`, ..., `top8`. Use these for positioning of the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum width=0pt, minimum height=6pt, font={\footnotesize}}]
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}{
    \draw (\n,0) node(bottom\n){}--(\n+.8,.8)--(\n+.8,2)node(top\n){}--(\n,1.2)--cycle;}
\foreach \n in {5,...,8}{
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (\n,0) node(bottom\n){}--(\n+.8,.8)--(\n+.8,2)node(top\n){}--(\n,1.2)--cycle;}
\draw [latex-] (top1.north)--node[above=1mm]{Transmission Order}(top8.north);
\draw [latex-latex] (bottom1.south)to[bend right=5]node[below=1mm]{Frames in Scene A}(bottom4.south);
\draw [latex-latex] (bottom5.south)to[bend right=5]node[below=1mm]{Frames in Scene B}(bottom8.south);
\draw [-latex, looseness=2] ([yshift=-1mm]bottom4.south)to[bend right=75]node[below=1mm]{Scene Change}([yshift=-1mm]bottom5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `pattern={north west lines}` (`\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`) to get the lines as in the questioner's image.